# Issue with PublishSubject and TestScheduler, item isn't emitted

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, rx-java, rx-android

I have been facing an issue with subjects and  TestSchedulers. My tests pass if I use a Trampoline scheduler but for some reason they fail if I use the TestScheduler.

Here's my sample test and relevant classes.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class DemoViewModelTest  {


    //Error Mocks
    private val actionsStream: PublishSubject<DemoContract.ViewEvent> = PublishSubject.create()

    private lateinit var viewModel: DemoViewModel

    private val handler = mock(DemoContract.Handler::class.java)

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        viewModel = DemoViewModel(schedulersProvider, handler)
        viewModel.viewEventsStream = actionsStream
    }

    @Test
    fun testUpdateCounter() {
        actionsStream.onNext(DemoContract.ViewEvent.UpdateClick)
        testScheduler.triggerActions()
        verify(handler).onUpdate()

    }


    protected var testScheduler = TestScheduler()

    protected var schedulersProvider: SchedulersProvider = object : SchedulersProvider() {
        override fun mainThread(): Scheduler {
            return testScheduler
        }

        override fun io(): Scheduler {
            return testScheduler
        }

        override fun computation(): Scheduler {
            return testScheduler
        }

        override fun newThread(): Scheduler {
            return testScheduler
        }

        override fun trampoline(): Scheduler {
            return testScheduler
        }

        override fun single(): Scheduler {
            return testScheduler
        }
    }
}
```

And my ViewModel class

```
class DemoViewModel (val schedulersProvider: SchedulersProvider, val handler:DemoContract.Handler) : DemoContract.ViewModel() {

    var viewEventsStream: Observable<DemoContract.ViewEvent>? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value
            subscribeToViewEvents()
        }

    private fun subscribeToViewEvents() {
        viewEventsStream?.let {
            it.subscribeOn(schedulersProvider.io())
                .observeOn(schedulersProvider.mainThread())
                .subscribe(object:Observer<DemoContract.ViewEvent>{
                    override fun onComplete() {

                    }

                    override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                    }

                    override fun onNext(t: DemoContract.ViewEvent) {
                        onViewEvent(t)
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    }

                })

        }
    }
     fun onViewEvent(event: DemoContract.ViewEvent) {
        when (event) {
            is DemoContract.ViewEvent.UpdateClick -> {
               handler.onUpdate()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and My Contract class is

```
interface DemoContract {
        abstract class ViewModel

        sealed class ViewEvent {
            object UpdateClick : ViewEvent()
        }

        interface Handler{
            fun onUpdate()
        }
    }
```

A few things about this, If I replace

```
viewModel.viewEventsStream = actionsStream
```

with

```
viewModel.viewEventsStream = Observable.just(DemoContract.ViewEvent.Update)
```

this test passes.

Can someone throw some light on this, thanks in advance. Here's the minimum runnable [project](https://gitlab.com/anvith/testissues)

Comment: What happens if you insert a logging statement before the `subscribeOn()` operator? Try `.doOnNext( v -> logger.debug(v.toString())` -

Comment: It doesn't get called, Here is a simple reproducible git project if you wish. https://gitlab.com/anvith/testissues

Comment: Check if `actionsStream.hasObservers` is true before calling `onNext`.

Comment: Is `subscribeToViewEvents` ever called?

Comment: @akarnokd The actionsStream.hasObservers is false, the subscribeToViewEvents is called as a result of `viewModel.viewEventsStream = actionsStream`. I've verified that the `onSubscribe` method is invoked with a subscription object. Also sorry about the cross post.

Comment: `actionsStream.hasObservers` is false <- this is the problem, you don't subscribe the right time so there is noone to receive the item.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks a lot @akarnokd for pointing me in the right direction. Turns out this is a race condition between the subscriber for the `PublishSubject` being added(`subscribeActual` call) and the onNext Call that I had trigger in my test. `onNext` call returns before the former happens.

The solution is to explicitly invoke `triggerActions` twice once immediately after subscription and once after emission.

Change this

```
    @Before
    fun setup() {
        viewModel = DemoViewModel(schedulersProvider, handler)
        viewModel.viewEventsStream = actionsStream
    }
```

To

```
    @Before
    fun setup() {
        viewModel = DemoViewModel(schedulersProvider, handler)
        viewModel.viewEventsStream = actionsStream
        testScheduler.triggerActions()
    }
```